# magento import product form csv file

Tags: import

i have problem importing product to magento using csv file

1: i have image url instead of image path , how can i save image from url as default magento takes path

2: it is difficult for layman to get catgory id and put in csv file.

i want to import product via catrgory name

cat 1 > child cat 1 > sub cat > rest product detail

how can i do this is there any module to do this

Answer (score 1):

I use magmi http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page - which supports both the image from a URL and the Category Import you are after

Images = http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

> Image Processor accepts URL as valid image location for any type of image (standard or extra) Image processor will download the remote images & put them in the appropriate directory for magento usage.

Example

...,image,media_gallery,....
....,http://someexternalserver.com/img/myimage.jpg;http://someexternalserver.com/img/extraimage1.jpg::myextralabel;....

Categories = http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer

Sample syntax taken from the wiki

```
level1/level2/level3;;level1bis/level2bis/level3bis
```

If you use magmi I recommend you password protect the magmi directory

Comment: magami is full of varunb , anyother way

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport which suppports image urls too.

I don't understand 2.

Comment: for 2: i want to say in magento default import we have to enter category id now i want use category name like baby > toy
and cloths > girls

Comment: I'm quite sure, that Import/Export supports ONLY that, so you have to use names?

Comment: can i use category name ??

Comment: When you use import/Export, yes. http://www.avs-webentwicklung.de/fileadmin/documents/20120512_Produktimport_ImportExport_eng.pdf

Comment: what to do i want to put just last level category name like baby toy( instead of toy > baby toy)

Comment: No clue. Write a module which replaces your category names with a path as a first step of your import.